# How to group by a column and return SUM of other columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm SELECTING values by ID of information and ANCHOR:

```
 SELECT 
      infoid, 
      anchor, 
      value 
 FROM 
      infodata 
 WHERE 
      (infoid = 1) 
      OR (infoid = 2)
      OR (infoid = 3)
 ORDER BY 
      anchor ASC
```

This query returns a list of infoid, anchors and numbers:

```
infoid      anchor     value
------      -----      -----
1           10         500
2           10         600
3           10         700

1           20         800
2           20         900
3           20         1000
```

How can I GROUP by ANCHOR and return SUM() values of 3 infos? return something like this:

```
anchor     value
-----      -----
10         500+600+700
20         800+900+1000
```

Comment: You've answered your own question already :) `SELECT anchor, SUM(value) FROM infodata GROUP BY anchor`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT
      anchor, 
      SUM(value) 
 FROM 
      infodata 
 WHERE 
      infoid IN (1,2,3)
 GROUP BY
      anchor
 ORDER BY 
      anchor ASC
```

Comment: Why not `infoid IN (1,2,3)`? MySQL seems to get easily confused by `OR` and doesn't optimize as well.

Comment: @tadman because the original question had ORs :) it's equivalent, but yes IN (1,2,3) looks better

Comment: +1 . . . I almost want to answer `group_concat(value separator '+')` ;).

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks a lot :) i was tempted as well... but i think the OP needs the actual sum ;)

Comment: thanks! this solved my question. but why use GROUP_CONCAT() in this case?

Comment: @user3175226 i said if you want exatcly result as you mentioned in your question. thats why i gave you this with group concat to get same result `500+600+700`

Answer (score 0):

If you want exactly same result as yours use this

```
SELECT
  anchor, 
  group_CONCAT(value separator '+') value
FROM  infodata 
WHERE infoid in (1,2,3)
GROUP BY anchor
ORDER BY anchor ASC;
```

Result:

```
 anchor     value
 -----      -----
 10         500+600+700
 20         800+900+1000
```